# Team Services Build Artifacts

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, msbuild-task

I'm attempting to create a build that will build my solution, apply web.config transforms as necessary and finally copy desired output (a built web api project) to the artifacts area of the build.

I'm using the Deployment...Azure WebApp Template with the Azure App Service Deploy step disabled (as we're in the middle of a move to Azure), with the following build arguments in the build step:

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

All works as expected, apart from the structure of the resulting zip file, which has the following structure:

{ZipFileName}{ProjectName\Content\C_C\a\1\s\Api{ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp...{BuildContent}

I'd like the content to be at the root of the published zip file if possible. Is the best way to manipulate the content of $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) using Powershell or a number of the other built in build tasks?

Comment: "which is in order to find the built project:" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes it was badly written, have edited.

Comment: @MattRowett Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @Matt, how did you get MSBuild step to generate a Web Deploy Package? I have used your suggested parameters for MSBuild, but I can't seem to get it to generate the zip.

Comment: @cesarb do you mean to deploy to an Azure App Service? If so there's a build task specifically for that. This was to get direct access to the nested build content output by the build step.

Comment: @MattRowett not to Azure App Service. I am just trying to get direct access to the content that MSBuild generates, specifically a Web Deploy Package. Which version of TFS are you using? Also, are you using XAML Build Definitions? Or the new version of builds?

Comment: @MattRowett, the issue for the build machine not generating the web deploy package was simply that the **Visual Studio Build Tools - Web Development Build Tools** were not installed. Once I installed them, the build agent was able to make the artifacts output as a Web Deploy Package for the web project.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to worry about it, because it won’t keep the folder structure (Just the files and folders in PackageTmp folder) after deploy to web server (e.g. IIS, Azure Web App)

If you still need to just include the files in PackageTmp folder, you can add build step to archive file to zip file through [Archive Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/archive-files) step.

For Visual Studio Build step, specify /p:DeployOnBuild=true to MSBuild Arguments.

[image]

Comment: Where would I see the resulting zip file? I don't an Artifacts link in the build summary.

Comment: Found it, I needed to put the archive step before the Publish Artifact step.

Comment: As I only want the built project in the artifact download for now, I simply changed the Publish Artifact...Path To Publish from $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) to {Project}I\obj\Dev\Package\PackageTmp\. This wasn't obvious until your post as the \obj folder doesn't exist in source control and can't be browsed to using the UI ellipsis.

Comment: @MattRowett Based on your original post, the structure is a\1\s\Api{ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp, so first, specify Api\{ProjectName]\bin to Path To Publish of Publish Build Artifact step if you only want the built project in the artifact download. Secondly, the obj folder doesn't exist in source control, you need to specify it directly (the value likes Api\[ProjectName]\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp, you can get the detail path in Visual Studio Build log (search CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy)